# How to create a usb stick that does a complete unattended installation of xubuntu

Tags: installation, xubuntu

We want to install several pc's with XUBUNTU from a usb stick. The user may not be asked any questions.

The installation must include kingsoft which is a dpkg. Is this possible?

Thanks

Joeri

Answer (score 0):

While i did a bit of searching i came across Ubuntu's Documentation on Automatic Installation, I figured you could do witht the help, and i guess you could USe it as a guide line

https://help.ubuntu.com/13.10/installation-guide/amd64/ch04s06.html

From Searching through the Docs, I Noticed not much changed through out the Releases, But i would find your distro release (Most likely a LTS) As Supported features may change...

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/i386/automatic-install.html